# Repeater и LINQ запрос, вывод на страницу ASP Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Не могу понять в чем у меня проблема

contacts.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ReapeterContacts" runat="server"  >

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="contact" class="table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ФИО</th>
                    <th>Компания</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>
               <%# Eval("firstname")%></b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("company")%></b>

            </td>



        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>

    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

contacts.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindTable();

    }


}




protected void BindTable() 
{

    using (contactsEntities db = new contactsEntities()) 
    {


        ReapeterContacts.DataSource = from p in db.persons
                                      join ph in db.phones on p.id equals ph.person_id into ljoin1
                                      from phone in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      join e in db.emails on p.id equals e.person_id into ljoin2
                                      from mail in ljoin2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          firstname = p.firstname,
                                          company = p.company
                                      };


        ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
    }
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Additional information: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to
```

Я вроде и вот так сделал

```
ReapeterContacts.DataSource = (from p in db.persons
                              join ph in db.phones on p.id equals ph.person_id into ljoin1
                              from phone in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join e in db.emails on p.id equals e.person_id into ljoin2
                              from mail in ljoin2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new
                              {
                                  firstname = p.firstname,
                                  company = p.company
                              }).ToList();
```

Но ничего не помогает. Как мне в таблицу вывести данные из базы? Где я не прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если вот так попробовать?

```
using (contactsEntities db = new contactsEntities()) 
{
    var result = from p in db.persons
                 join ph in db.phones on p.id equals ph.person_id into ljoin1
                 from phone in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join e in db.emails on p.id equals e.person_id into ljoin2
                 from mail in ljoin2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                    firstname = p.firstname,
                    company = p.company
                 };

   ReapeterContacts.DataSource = result.ToList();
   ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
}
```

**UPDATE**
А зачем Вам такой сложный запрос если нужно только firstname и company?
Может проще вот так

```
using (contactsEntities db = new contactsEntities()) 
{
    var result = from p in db.persons
                 select new
                 {
                    firstname = p.firstname,
                    company = p.company
                 };

   ReapeterContacts.DataSource = result.ToList();
   ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
}
```

Или так

```
using (contactsEntities db = new contactsEntities()) 
{
   var result = db.persons.Select(x=> new { x.firstname, x.company});

   ReapeterContacts.DataSource = result.ToList();
   ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
}
```

Или так (честно говоря не совсем в курсе как работает биндинг в ASP Webforms)

```
using (contactsEntities db = new contactsEntities()) 
{
   var result = db.persons.Select(x=> new {
                                             firstname = x.firstname,
                                             company = x.company
                                           });

   ReapeterContacts.DataSource = result.ToList();
   ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
}
```